# Time Complexity Analysis of Matrix Operation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

What is the Time Complexity of the Following operation `X'(X transponse) ans XX'`
Could you explain me the cost of these operation in time complexity domain  ?

 What is the time Complexity of `X^-1 (X inverse)`

Finally getting all the Operation done at same time `(XX')^-1`

Comment: Inverse: $O(n^3)$. For the entire thing, $O(n^2(n+m))$, where $X$ is a $n\times m$ matrix.

Comment: This has better bounds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations#Matrix_algebra